# How can I split a partition in a RAID1 array on ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, raid, fdisk, disk-management

I just purchased a brand new server on OVH with disk specification: 2 x480GB of SSD SOFT. When I do `df -h`, the output is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G   13G  5.7G  69% /
devtmpfs         16G   12K   16G   1% /dev
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            3.2G  792K  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/md2        421G   17G  383G   5% /home
```

Mind you I have stored many files and then I realized that I need much bigger space for root. Now I could either replace the 2 `/dev/root` with `/dev/md2` and change boot drive or I could partition `/dev/md2` with is attached on home (the data there can be deleted, backup is there) into 2 parts 200GB each and then mount one of the partition to `/var/www/tmp` to store the files needed during the working of sites. or I can resize the root partition. Output of `lsblk` is :

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0  19.5G  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0  19.5G  0 raid1 /
├─sda2    8:2    0 427.1G  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0 427.1G  0 raid1 /home
└─sda3    8:3    0   511M  0 part  [SWAP]
sdb       8:16   0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0  19.5G  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0  19.5G  0 raid1 /
├─sdb2    8:18   0 427.1G  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0 427.1G  0 raid1 /home
└─sdb3    8:19   0   511M  0 part  [SWAP]
```

Now I don't know which partition to edit. I thought to do something like this, `sudo fdisk /dev/sda2` (/home) and then delete the partition and then create 2 equal but now I can't decide it. Should I do it on `/dev/sda2` or `/dev/sdb2`. What is the difference?

Thank you for the help and I know it's a confusing question.